# Header Background - Margin-Left

Tags: css, header

I have a forum site @ http://forum.banaisbul.com

As you see there is a bacground problem in the header, I cannot manage to set a full gray background color. When I use margin-left code, it always shows a White bacground instead of gray.

here is the code I use:

Can you tell me where I'm being wrong?

Comment: Please try to change margin-left: 200px; to padding-left: 200px; and the problem will get fixed.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using margin or padding for that logo. It doesn't line up with your content correctly. Try resizing your browser to better understand. You'll want to set up your header something more like this (http://jsfiddle.net/qe6t7zpv/). Notice the red box (logo) stays left-aligned with the text below the header.

Comment: @RadGH Thank you for your feedback, when i try to resize my browser, indeed I see it does not line up with my content. But I really could not understand your code at the jsfiddle. How should I code it to line up really?

Comment: Add a div inside your header. Put the logo in that div. Center the div and give it a max width of 960 (`margin: 0 auto; max-width: 960px;`). Then that div will stay in line with your content, but you can still give a background image to the original header. Remove padding/margin from your logo, as its no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the margin-left to padding-left and it works.

The difference between margin and padding is that the margin is the space rendered outside the element, between itself and other elements. By setting a left margin, you are moving the entire header and thereby its background color.

A padding, on the other hand, is the space WITHIN the element, between its outside border and its contents. In this case, it moves the contents (i.e. the image) but not the entire header. Because the header element itself remains in its place, the background color is also visible in the top left corner beside the image.

Comment: You "answer" should be a comment.

Comment: Okay, I'll have a look at the guidelines... To me, this seems like an answer to the question.

Comment: Your contribution might solve the OP's problem, but one-sentence posts are rarely considered a good answer.

Comment: Okay, you're right. I'll edit my answer and make it a good one.